# Extjs Component Query .down()

Tags: extjs, components, textfield, traversal

I seem to be struggling with something I have used a million times! I dont understand why all of a sudden it doesnt work anymore :)

My Layout

```
an accordion 
    > toolbar
    > tabs
        >tab 1
            > form.panel 1
                > textfield (alias: 'widget.mytextfield')
            > form.panel 2
        >tab 2
            > form.panel 1
```

Now heres the problem... when im at panel 1 and I try to access the textfield (mytextfield)

```
//panel, being 'tab 1 > panel 1'
var textfield = panel.down('mytextfield')
```

It just returns null.

My output for

```
console.info(panel.down());
```

is the header of the panel (so im def at the right location) -> it seems as if it cant find the body of the panel

Any ideas? Totally stuck!

The only way I get get 'mytextfield' is with

```
var textfield = panel.items.items[0];
```

But if the textfield changes order then the above code wouldnt work anymore of course

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've figured something out... which is strange

If I take the textfield out of the panel and place it in a separate file. Then include it using `requires`. I can access the textfield with `.down()`

For example in my main form panel

```
...
requires:['App.view.MyTextField'],
items:[{
    xtype:'mytextfield' //i can access you with .down()
},{
    xtype:'textfield',
    alias:'widget.mytextfield2' //you are showing up - but I CANT access you with .down() - only panel.items.items[0]
}]
...
```

MyTextField

```
Ext.define('App.view.MyTextField', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Textfield',
    alias:'widget.mytextfield'
});
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How and where do you get your parent panel component?

http://jsfiddle.net/UBb8n/1/ — works for me.

**UPDATED**:

According to [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-alias):

> **alias**:
>   List of short aliases for class names.
>   Most useful for defining xtypes for widgets.

So keep in mind that `items: {xtype: 'blah'}` != `Ext.define('My.Class.Blah', {alias: 'widget.blah'})`.
First it's just an instantiation of the second one.

And `alias: 'widget.mycoolpanel'` is just a shorthand for helper function `Ext.widget` that searches components with `xtype: 'widget.<…>'`.

Comment: i updated your example... it doesnt work if you define the alias inside the items:[] config... but in essence they should be identical - http://jsfiddle.net/UBb8n/3/

Comment: Basically, you can't declare an alias inline. An alias is only valid when you're defining a class.

Comment: yea i realise the mistake I made. Thanks o_nix and @Evan Trimboli